# C# How do I check if one of two values is TRUE?

Tags: c#, boolean-logic

Should be a simple question for the C# experts here.

I basically want to check if one value or another is TRUE, a wild stab at the code is below:

```
if ((Boolean.Parse(staff.getValue("Male")) | Boolean.Parse(staff.getValue("Female")))    
{   
   // is true
}
```

Is this correct?

Thanks

Comment: do you mean at least one of the values is true, or exactly one of the values is true?

Comment: wouldn't "is male OR is female" always be true? On Earth, anyway?

Comment: @Ray, what if there's a transsexual or "prefer not to answer" option?

Comment: @Ray That's not entirely true any more.

Comment: @Matt - I live in the Midwest - we don't have those options here

Comment: @Null - what kind of movies are you watching/?

Comment: This is going downhill quickly.  What were we talking about?

Comment: @Ray See http://language.home.sprynet.com/otherdex/22enuf.htm

Answer (score 18):

If EXACTLY ONE should be true then it is:

```
var male = bool.Parse(staff.getValue("Male"));
var female = bool.Parse(staff.getValue("Female"));

if (male ^ female)    
{
   //is true
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Sounds like you're looking for the logical OR.

```
if(condition1 || condition2)
{
}
```

Comment: The code given in the question already uses *one* of the logical OR operators -- `|` -- although I agree that it's almost always preferable to use the short-circuiting `||` version instead.

Comment: @LukeH `|` is not logical OR operator. It is bitwise OR operator.

Comment: @Markos: Not in C#. For type `Boolean`, operator `|` is a non-shortcircuiting logical OR operator.

Comment: @Markos: From the MSDN docs: *"For `bool` operands, `|` computes the logical OR of its operands"* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx.aspx

Comment: @Gorpik of course, bitwise operation on one bit is in fact non-shortcirtuiting logical operation.

Comment: @Markos: But it happens that in C# this operator is specifically defined as a non-shortcircuiting logical operator, as explained in LukeH's link. It is a question of concept. So your first comment is wrong.

Answer (score 8):

Use the `||` (double pipe), logical OR.

```
bool isMale = Boolean.Parse(staff.getValue("Male");
bool isFemale = Boolean.Parse(staff.getValue("Female");
if (isMale || isFemale) // note double pipe ||
{
   // do something if true
}
```

In C# statement expressions are evaluated from left to right. In an OR operation, the second expression will not be evaluated if the first one equals true.

Answer (score 4):

The conditional OR operator `||` is what you need

```
if ((Boolean.Parse(staff.getValue("Male")) || Boolean.Parse(staff.getValue("Female")))
{
   //is true
}
```

If the first condition is `TRUE`, then the second condition isn't checked since the outcome is obviously going to return `TRUE`.

Comment: The `|` operator, as used by the example code in the question, is also a logical OR operator, although I agree that it's almost always preferable to use the short-circuiting `||` version instead.

Comment: My bad - I edited it to 'conditional' as that's how I've seen it being called.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `TryParse` works more fast and more safe then just `Parse` because doesn't throw an exception in case of error. `TryParse` returns bool that indicates was parse successful or was not.

So both parsing methods should return `true` and only after that - do the main check

```
bool male, female;
if ((Boolean.TryParse(staff.getValue("Male"), out male) && 
     Boolean.TryParse(staff.getValue("Female"), out female)) &&
    (male || female)) // or ^
{
    // do stuff
}
```

or

```
bool male, female;
if (Boolean.TryParse(staff.getValue("Male"), out male) &&
     Boolean.TryParse(staff.getValue("Female"), out female))        
{
    if(male) { }
    else if (female) { } // or just else
}
else
{
     // staff contains wrong data. Probably "yeap" instead of "true"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To indicate whether a gender is specified with a value of "true" rather than "false",

```
bool genderIsSpecified = staff.getValue("Male") | staff.getValue("Female");
```

.. will only determine whether it's one of those values, not which of those values the object `staff` is.

So, just in case this question is literal and not an abstract example, ...

Male or Female .. everyone is one or the other. Perhaps in your question you meant to ask which of the two is the case? In that case,

```
bool defaultGenderIfNoGenderDocumented = true; // male
bool MaleIfTrue_FemaleIfFalse = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(staff.getValue("Male"))
    ? bool.Parse(staff.getValue("Male"))
    : string.IsNullOrEmpty(staff.getValue("Female"))
        ? bool.Parse(staff.getValue("Female"))
            ? false
            : defaultGenderIfNoGenderDocumented
        : defaultGenderIfNoGenderDocumented;
```

Or simply,

```
// assume value is properly populated, ignore "Female" value
bool isMale = bool.Parse(staff.getValue("Male"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a similar scenario but I am checking for three or more bool values.

```
Thread th = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        bool allReadComplete = true;

                        foreach (IDataProvider provider in lstDataProviders)
                        {
                            provider.StartReading();

                            if (provider.FinishedReading)
                              allReadComplete = allReadComplete && provider.FinishedReading;
                            else
                              allReadComplete = provider.FinishedReading;
                        }

                        // to induce some context switching
                        Thread.Sleep(0);

                        if (allReadComplete)
                            break;
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Thread Exiting");

                });
            th.IsBackground = true;
            th.Start();
```

Answer (score -3):

A little exception checking is needed anyway. The Boolean.Parse() method gets a string as argument and returns either **`true`** or **`false`** *only if* the argument, once stripped out of whitespace, is equal to "True" or "False" (note capitalization). In ANY other case the function returns an exception.

Supposing that the possible values of `staff.getValue("Male")` and `staff.getValue("Female")` are exactly those two, then the simple disjunction (`||`) is sufficient. If **any** other return value is possible, including `null` and the empty string, then you have to check for exceptions

```
bool isMale;
try {
    isMale = Boolean.Parse(staff.getValue("Male"));
} catch(Exception e) {
    isMale = Boolean.False;
}
try {
    isFemale = Boolean.Parse(staff.getValue("Female"));
} catch(Exception e) {
    isFemale = Boolean.False;
}
if (isMale || isFemale) // note double pipe ||
{
    // do something if true
}
```

or compare manually

```
bool isMale = Boolean.TrueValue == staff.getValue("Male");
bool isFemale = Boolean.TrueValue == staff.getValue("Female");
if (isMale || isFemale) // note double pipe ||
{
    // do something if true
}
```

Comment: According to MSDN Boolean.Parse is case-insensitive.  And this would be a good place to use Boolean.TryParse instead of Boolean.Parse to avoid having to do exception handling.

Comment: What is Boolean.True and even if it were valid, what is the virtue of comparing it again to a boolean?  This could go on for ever: `= Boolean.True == staff.getValue("Female") == true == true == true...... == true`.  Whats the point?

Comment: You aren't "checking for exceptions." You are "swallowing exceptions and making people who inherit your code tear their hair out." This is exactly what NOT to do with exceptions; if parsing the booleans might fail, use `TryParse()` as Phil Lamb suggested. If finding a null return value will just mean you assign `false` to isMale or isFemale anyway, just use the null-coalescing operator, "??". http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx. i.e. `isMale = staff.getValue() ?? false;`

Comment: Phil: Completely agree!!!!


Michael: Typo, it was meant to be: `isMale = Boolean.TrueString == staff.getValue("Male")` and not `isMale = Boolean.True == staff.getValue("Male")`.


jloubert: Rather `Boolean.Parse(staff.getValue() ?? Boolean.FalseString)` (or with TryParse).